# Loading data to Hive using tez engine and ambari logs shows complete but logs hang without completing the Insert into those partitions

Tags: logging, hive, ambari, apache-tez

We are loading data into a hive table using tez execution engine. The jobs we use to load is in running state but on the ambari for the application id, we see it as succeeded and from the logs we could see it is stuck .
It had around 90 partitions and the volume is also pretty similar. Jobs run on a day basis and load somewhere around 3 months of data.

Example for a stuck log:

```
Partition aa.db.tablename{dt=2020-02-06} stats: [numFiles=42, numRows=265732, totalSize=9005011, rawDataSize=34024246] 
Partition aa.db.tablename{dt=2020-02-07} stats: [numFiles=42, numRows=265853, totalSize=9310285, rawDataSize=34399056]
```

Example for a successful log:

```
Partition aa.db.tablename{dt=2020-02-06} stats: [numFiles=42, numRows=265732, totalSize=9005011, rawDataSize=34024246] 
Partition aa.db.tablename{dt=2020-02-07} stats: [numFiles=42, numRows=265853, totalSize=9310285, rawDataSize=34399056] 

OK 
Time taken: 1385.571 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting this property to false helped us in loading the data
`set hive.stats.autogather=false;`

As we had more than 400 partitions, we also disabled 
`set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=false;`
but this is more of stopping the bleeding and a temp patch.